# netty http file example: why ssl handler uses a different way to write messages?

Tags: java, http, ssl, netty

The example code:
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java

if ssl is disabled, it uses FileRegion instead of ChunkedInput.  Why is that?  Won't a large file break the code?

Thanks.

Comment: It turned out to be calling FileChannel's transferTo() method when ssl is disabled.  That method is more efficient than reading from a channel or some wrappings of ByteBuf.

Comment: Can you post that as a answer, this question is really interesting for future people seeing that

Comment: Why would a large file break the code?

Comment: I was wrong.  At first I thought if ChunkedInput is not used then the message size may be larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.  Now I dived into the code and find that in that case the size will be set to 0 and FileChannel's transferTo() method is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be calling FileChannel's transferTo() method when ssl is disabled. That method is more efficient than reading from a channel or some wrappings of ByteBuf.  And when the request is passed to channel the size of the message will be set to 0 in that case.